# using server configuration instead of .htaccess in Phalcon, something can't be load

Tags: apache, .htaccess, phalcon

My .htaccess files below:

```
##/.htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ public/    [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

#/public/.htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

when I try using server configuration instead of .htaccess, something can't be load. my server configuration file below:

```
....
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^/?public/(.*)$ /public/index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule  ^$ /public/    [L]
RewriteRule  (.*) /public/$1 [L]
....
```

when I get the image, it call error:
ImgController handler class cannot be loaded

What's worng ?
Thx.

Comment: The problem has solved,it is my configuration problem, for the following configuration to solve the problem:     RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule  ^$ /public/    [L]

    RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/(.*)$
    RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ /public$1

    RewriteCond  %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond  %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^/public/(.*)$ /public/index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]

    RewriteRule .* - [L]